# Python нужна помощь с сортировкой

Tags: python, сортировка

Мне необходимо отсортировать список по возрастанию. В качестве параметра сортировки необходимо указать длину списка каждого item после выполнения над ним разбиения по определенном параметру split("paramater")

```
def sorted(items):
    return sorted(items, key = )
```

**Вход:**

```
0.2090000.ru
0.fls.doubleclick.net
0.hiveon.net
0.internet.org
0.r.bat.bing.com
0.r.msn.com
```

**Выход:**

```
0.2090000.ru          - 3 
0.hiveon.net          - 3
0.internet.org        - 3
0.fls.doubleclick.net - 4
0.r.msn.com           - 4
0.r.bat.bing.com      - 5
```

Что в key указывать? Как ссылаться на item в items?

Comment: Приведите в вопросе небольшой, но воспроизводимый пример входных данных и то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе.

Comment: @MaxU добавил входные и выходные данные

Comment: А какой смысл разбивать, если можно просто посчитать количество? `sorted(items, key=lambda x: x.count("."))`

Comment: @andreymal ну да можно и так, просто в голову первое что пришло в голову, это разбиение

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Исходный список:

```
In [60]: items
Out[60]:
['0.2090000.ru',
 '0.fls.doubleclick.net',
 '0.hiveon.net',
 '0.internet.org',
 '0.r.bat.bing.com',
 '0.r.msn.com']
```

список, отсортированный по количеству элементов строки разбитой по символу `"."`:

```
In [61]: sorted(items, key=lambda x: len(x.split(".")))
Out[61]:
['0.2090000.ru',
 '0.hiveon.net',
 '0.internet.org',
 '0.fls.doubleclick.net',
 '0.r.msn.com',
 '0.r.bat.bing.com']
```

того же результата сортировки можно добиться посчитав число точек в в каждой строке:

```
In [62]: sorted(items, key=lambda x: x.count("."))
Out[62]:
['0.2090000.ru',
 '0.hiveon.net',
 '0.internet.org',
 '0.fls.doubleclick.net',
 '0.r.msn.com',
 '0.r.bat.bing.com']
```

**NOTE:** создавая свои функции или переменные не используйте зарезервированных имён:

```
def sorted(items):    #  <--- ваша функция `sorted()` "затенит" встроенную `sorted()` !
    return sorted(items, key = )
```

после данного определения вы "затенили" встроенную функцию `sorted()` своей и уже не сможете вызвать `sorted()` с дополнительными параметрами...